# Divisibility using binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I have to prove that $6 \mid n^3 + 5n$ in a number of ways. One that I've been finding impossible is binomial coefficients. This is the problem statment:

> Use an expression in terms of binomial coefficients to prove $n^3 + 5n$ is divisible by $6$.

Comment: Hint: this is true if and only if $n^3 - n$ is divisible by $6$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\rm\displaystyle\ \ n^3+5\:n\ =\ n^3-n + 6\:n\ =\ (n+1)\:n\:(n-1) + 6\:n\ =\ 6\ {n+1\choose 3} + 6\ {n\choose 1}$$

In fact it is a classical result of Polya and Ostrowski (1920) that any integer valued polynomial, i.e. any $\rm\:f(x)\in \mathbb Q[x]\:$ with $\rm\:f(\mathbb Z)\subset \mathbb Z\:,\:$ is an integral linear combination of binomial coefficients, see for example Polya And Szego, *Problems and theorems in analysis*, vol II, [Problem 85 p. 129](http://books.google.com/books?id=pCa2CmAt8pwC&pg=PA129) and its [solution on p. 320.](http://books.google.com/books?id=pCa2CmAt8pwC&pg=PA320) These results have been extended to much more general rings (e.g. Dedekind domains) by Cahen at al.

Comment: It is easy to verify that $x^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x}{k} k! S^{(2)}_{n,k}$, where $S^{(2)}_{n,k}$ are Stirling numbers of the second kind, so it follows for $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Which book should I look at for proof for $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ ? Thanks

Comment: @Sasha See the newly added links in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It so happens that $n^3+5n = 6 \left( \binom{n}{3} + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{1} \right)$.

Your result follows because binomial coefficients are integers.