# Divisibility of composite numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am having difficulty in solving following types of problem:

Sometimes we are given a number in terms of $n$ and we have to check whether it is divisible by a particular composite number.  For example, I am posting a question here

> suppose $k= n^5- n$ then prove that $k$ is divisible by $30$.

And this was my approach:

> $$n^5-n= n (n^4-1) =n(n^2+1) (n+1) (n-1)$$
>   Since $k$ is a product of $n^2+1$ and three consecutive integers, it must be a multiple of $2$ and $3$. So it gives $k= 6m (n^2+1)$. But how can I prove that it's also a multiple of 5? And this is where I  get confused.

Now, suggest some alternate way to prove above problem or some corrections in my method.

Comment: This turns out to be identical to [How to prove $n^5−n$ is divisible by 30 without reduction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132210/how-to-prove-n5-n-is-divisible-by-30-without-reduction)