# "Question: Show that $n^5 - n$ is divisible by 30; for all natural n"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Show that $n^5 - n$ is divisible by $30;$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

I tried to solve this three-way. And all stopped at some point.

I) By induction:
testing for $0$, $1$ and $2$ It is clearly true.
As a hypothesis, we have $30|n^5-n\Rightarrow n^5-n=30k$.
Therefore, the thesis would $30|(n+1)^5-n-1\Rightarrow (n+1)^5-n-1=30j$. By theorem binomial $(n+1)^5-n-1=n^5+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n+1-n-1$ $=30k+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n.$
It was a little messy and not given to proceed.

II)I tried by Fermat's Little Theorem:
$$30|n^5-n\Rightarrow 5\cdot3\cdot2|n^5-n $$
Analyzing each case, we have; clearly $5|n^5-n$ (Fermat's Little Theorem). Now cases $3|n^5-n$ and $2|n^5-n$ I could not develop.

III)In this I wanted your help especially like to solve using this because this exercise on this handout (Properties of the Greatest Common Divisor). Would show that
$$gcd(n^5-n,30)=30$$
Are detailers, please, because'm coursing Theory of the numbers the first time. In the third semester of the degree course in mathematics
What would be the idea to solve this by using the Greatest Common? This problem in this handout GCD?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/132210/, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/174558/  (found by copying the question into Google)

Comment: Somehow you changed $n^5-n$ into $n^5-5$ in a few places. You might want to reexamine those.

Comment: @rschwieb: Correction made​​, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily prove it by induction

$$(n+1)^5-(n+1)=(n^5-n)+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n=(n^5-n)+5n\left( n^3+2n^2+2n+1 \right)$$
$$=(n^5-n)+5n(n+1)\left( n^2+n+1 \right)$$
$$=(n^5-n)+5n(n+1)\left( (n-1)^2-3n\right)$$
$$=(n^5-n)+5n(n+1)(n-1)^2-15n^2(n+1)$$

- is divisible by $30$ by the inductive assumption
- $n(n+1)(n-1)$ is the product of three consecutive integers, thus divisible by $2$ and $3$.
- $n(n+1)$ is even.

**Added** If you use induction probably the best way to approach the problem is by observing that the inductive step reduces to

$$30|5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n=5\left( n^4+2n^3+2n^2+n \right)$$
which is equivalent to

$$6|n^4+2n^3+2n^2+n$$
Treat this as a **new** induction problem.

Note that the degree of the polynomial decreased by $1$, and the inductive step, if not obvious, is also a similar problem but the degree again one less. Repeat until you get an obvious statement...

Comment: Perfect. I understand your reasoning, but I have difficulties in making these factorizations, can you make using division of polynomials?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior Check the new addition to the answer.

Comment: @N.S. Reduction of degree is not clear to me. I tried doing that but did not succeed.

Answer (score 12):

Try factoring:

$$n^5-n=n(n+1)(n-1)(n^2+1)$$

Now, at least one of three consecutive numbers $n-1,n,n+1$ is divisible by $3$, and at least one is divisible by $2$.  If none are divisible by $5$, can you show that this implies that $n^2+1$ is divisible by $5$?

Comment: nice! In absence of inspiration, one can always look at all the results of $n^5-n$ mod $30$, for $n=0,1,\dots,29$.

Comment: Or you can still look at $n = 0,1$ mod $2$, $n = 0,1,2$ mod $3$, $n = 0,1,2,3,4$ mod $5$, which is not that much work even without factoring.

Comment: @nikoma
nikoma and dkuper, Yet arrived at the contents of mod Unfortunately, but soon, hopefully studying.

Answer (score 3):

**Method** $1:$

$$n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2-4+5)$$
$$=n(n^2-1)(n^2-4)+5n(n^2-1)$$
$$=\underbrace{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}_{\text{ product of }5\text{ consecutive integers  }}+5\underbrace{(n-1)n(n+1)}_{\text{ product of }3\text{ consecutive integers  }}$$

Now, we know the product $r$ consecutive integers is [divisible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-without-using-the-prop) by $r!$ where $r$ is a positive integer

---

**Method** $2:$

Using Fermat's Little Theorem, $n^p\equiv n\pmod p$ for prime $p$

$\implies 5$ divides $n^5-n$

$n^5-n=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=(n^3-n)(n^2+1)$

As $3$ divides $n^3-n\implies 3$ divides $n^5-n$

$n^5-n=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)=(n^2-n)(n+1)(n^2+1)$

As $2$ divides $n^2-n\implies 2$ divides $n^5-n$

$\implies $lcm $(2,3,5)$ divides $n^5-n$

Answer (score 1):

Factor it .

$$n^5-n=n(n+1)(n-1)(n^2+1)$$

1.) Three consecutive integers will be divisible by 2 and 3 .

2.)If $n^2 - 4$ is divisible by 5 then $n^2+1$ is also divisible by 5.

3.)Put $ n^2 - 4$ in place of $n^2+1$

4.) We get $$ n^5-n=(n+1)(n)(n-1)(n-2)(n+2) $$
Which is a product of 5 consecutive integers . And Hence it is divisible by 5 as well .

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n^5-n}{30} = 4\binom{n}{5} + 8\binom{n}{4} + 5\binom{n}{3} + \binom{n}{2} -n $$

(In fact, every polynomial which takes values in $\mathbf{Z}$ can be expressed as a sum of binomial coefficients with integer coefficients, as above, so this was not magic.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, just to feed the imagination for similar problems.

For the factors $2$ and $3$ use @Jared's factorisation.

For the factor $5$ note that the squares modulo $5$ are $0, \pm 1$ and use $n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)$ (or little Fermat, because $5$ is prime).

The point was to draw attention to the squares, since these are sometimes useful and/or significant.