# Show that $30$ divides $n^{5} - n$, where n is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I started to think about this problem and then factored $n^5 - n$ to $(n^2 - 1)(n^2 + 1)(n)$, and later to $(n-1)(n)(n+1)(n^2 + 1)$. I know that $(n-1)(n)(n+1)$ is divisible by $6$, but it is not that case $5$ divides $n^2 + 1$ for any integer $n$, so i can´t use the multiplication property. Can anyone help me finish this proof?

Comment: Also: [How to prove $n^5 - n$ is divisible by 30 without reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132210/how-to-prove-n5-n-is-divisible-by-30-without-reduction) – all found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24n%5E5%20-%20n%24&p=1)

Comment: $5$ doesn't have to divide $n^2+1$.  $5$ could divide $n$, or $n-1$ or $n+1$.  Can you prove that $5$ must divide one of those $4$ values?  Hint: How can $5$ *not* divide any of the $n, n+1, n-1$?  If $5$ divides non of those three, what possible remainder is there if you divide $n$ by $5$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$(n^2-1)(n^2+1)n=(n^2-1)(n^2-4+5)n=\underbrace{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}_{\text{product of } 5\text{ consecutive integers}}+5n(n^2-1)$$

Comment: Thanks, it wasn´t hard after all.

Comment: @MateusBuarque, Welcome! **See also**: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial

Comment: Oops, i made a mistake, i wanted to prove if it for 30, but this strategy still works.

Comment: @MateusBuarque, That's also done here using the link I have just shared

Answer (score 1):

One of the other answers requires that you know something - the other is very clever. A hint for a proof that doesn't require either non-trivial theorems or cleverness: $n=5k+j$, where $j\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a particular case of fermats little theorem