# Irreducible polynomials for that each output is divisible by an integer n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Feel free to delete this question if it has been asked somewhere else before.

I've recently stumbled upon [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132210/how-to-prove-n5-n-is-divisible-by-30-without-reduction) question on the Mathematics StackExchange and I've wondered how the polynomials for higher n would look. I am asking for irreducible polynomials, because without this restriction, one would get trivial polynomials like $f(x) = n*x$ for which each output is divisible by n. These can be reduced by e.g. the constant factor $n$ and hence would not be irreducible. If it is unclear, by "irreducible" I mean "irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$", so only integer polynomials are allowed, no (ir)rationals.

I've made a bit of progress on this problem regarding some values of $n$ that I will list below. I am also well aware that many questions asking for specific cases have already been answered and I would just like to expand on them.

$n = 1: f(x) = x + C \land C \in \mathbb{Z}$. All of these are irreducible.

$n = 2: f(x) = x^2 + x + C$ or $f(x) = x^2 - x + C \land C \in \mathbb{Z} \land C \equiv 0 \mod{2}$. This is basically equivalent to stating that C must be even. Again, all of these are irreducible.

At this point I will omit the $C$ - term and just state that $ C \in \mathbb{Z} \land C \neq 0 \land C \equiv 0 \mod{n}$ for all n. Correct me if I am wrong on that.

In the question mentioned [above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132210/how-to-prove-n5-n-is-divisible-by-30-without-reduction), a polynomial for $n = 30$ is showcased, that can be made irreducible with a little bit of tweaking for C:

$n = 30: f(x) = x^5 - x + 30$. Thus $C = 30$.

This short analysis has lead me to a couple of questions:

> (1) Are there infinitely many, non-trivial (irreducible) polynomials for a given n? If not, how many are there for a certain n? Is it bounded in any way?
>
> (2) Does a pattern in the generated polynomials exist, or at least for a part of them?
>
> (3) Is there a more efficient way than trial-and-error backtracking when trying to find a polynomial for given n?

So far I've just tried to find examples by trial-and-error and I am excited if there is any theory behind this question. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Oh, and with "Trial and Error" I mean I looked at quadratic, cubic,... congruences for modulo n.

Comment: It would improve the body of your Question to spell out that you are interested in integer polynomials *irreducible over* $\mathbb Z$ (or equivalently, primitive and irreducible over $\mathbb Q$).  If you simply mean the greatest common divisor of coefficients is $1$, this is conveyed by the term *primitive* integer polynomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (2), I suspect it will be very hard to characterise all such polynomials, but one approach would be to consider a result from Polya and Ostrowski (1920) which states that every integer to integer polynomial must be a linear sum of binomial coefficients.

The answer to the other two parts is yes: Consider $(x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-n)$, which clearly works.

Just as an aside, your definition of "irreducible" is not what most people mean -- for instance, $x^5-x=x(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$ is reducible.

As a double aside:

Let $P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-n)+pn$ for a prime $p>(2n)!\,$ Then we know that, by iterated triangle inequality, the polynomial $P(x)$ has no complex roots of magnitude less than $n$ (Suppose $|\alpha|<n$ is a root. Then $|(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)\ldots(\alpha-n)|<(2n)!<pn$). Now suppose $P(x)=Q(x)R(x)$ for integer polynomials $Q,R$. Then the constant term of one of the polynomials is divisible by $p$, so the constant term of the other polynomial has absolute value at most $n$, so by Vieta's formula, it has at least one root with absolute value at most $n$, a contradiction.

Thus the family of $P$ above is an infinite family of solutions to the original question.

Comment: ... but with a little adjustment we find the irreducible $x^5-x+60$

Comment: Ah yes, it is even stated in the other question. I forgot that, my bad. But the question still stands then for n = 30, since the construction method you mentioned builds off smaller polynomials and thus is reducible. @HagenvonElitzen Huh, that's interesting. Did you find it by accident/trial and error or did you apply a specific method?

Comment: Technically speaking, your answer "builds off" smaller polynomials too. But anyways if you want you can just add a constant $kn$ to the end of the thing and it'll work

Comment: @auscrypt I've just noticed that too. Damn. Is this really irreducible for each C (with the restrictions stated above)? I think it is, but I'm too lazy to see if I can prove it.

Comment: I'll accept your answer anyway since you've shown a (hopefully) valid way to generate these. Thanks!

Comment: If you want, you can add a constant term (+kn) and the polynomial will... probably(?) be irreducible. Still working on it, will update if it gets solved.