# Prove that $n^{31} \equiv n$ mod $77$ for all integers $n$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

**Question**:

> Prove that $n^{31} \equiv n$ mod $77$ for all integers $n$

---

I've read this question: [How to prove $n^5 - n$ is divisible by $30$ without reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132210/how-to-prove-n5-n-is-divisible-by-30-without-reduction) But I don't know how to use the same method to prove my example.

Induction seems very long and unnecessary.

I tried to come up with something using:

- $n^7 \equiv n \mod{7}$ and
- $n^{11} \equiv n \mod{11}$

but I am not sure that's useful.

I am now assuming I have to show that $n^{31} - n$ is a multiple of 7 and 11 and thus a multiple of 77. How do I arrive in this conclusion?

Comment: read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function

Comment: Use the same methods as in the linked diupe.

Comment: See also the "Linked" questions in the sidebar of the dupe for many worked examples.

Answer (score 0):

Let's work $\pmod {7}$: in this case you have $a^6 \equiv 1$ for all $a \neq 0$. Then
$$n^{31} \equiv (n^5)^{6} \cdot n \equiv 1 \cdot n \equiv n$$

If we work $\pmod {11}$, we have $a^{10} \equiv 1$ for all $a \neq 0$. Then
$$n^{31} \equiv (n^3)^{10} \cdot n \equiv 1 \cdot n \equiv n$$

Comment: Why is $a^{6} \equiv 1 \mod{7}$ valid for all a != 0 ? Doesn't the theorem hold only if a is not divisible by 7 by Fermat's theorem?

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs. We already have hundreds of anowers on this topic.