# Is this a valid proof for $n^{5} - n$ is divisible by 30?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know this question was asked in this thread [How to prove n^5−n is divisible by 30 without reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132210/how-to-prove-n5-n-is-divisible-by-30-without-reduction) but my reputation is too low to comment. Here's how I approached it:

By Fermat's Little Theorem: $n^{p-1} \equiv\ 1 (\textrm{mod}\ p)$ where p is prime.
30 can be factored as (5)(6). $n^5 - n$ can be rewritten as $n(n^4 - 1)$. Therefore, my proof for 30 divides $n^5 - n$ is as follows:

$n(n^{4} -1)\equiv\ n(1 -1) \equiv\ 0 (\textrm{mod}\ 5(6))$.

Is this valid? All the comments in the other thread to something that seems overly complicated.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note that [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) states that $n^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ for primes $p$ occurs *only* where $n$ doesn't contain any factors of $p$. Nonetheless, $n^{p}\equiv n\pmod{p}$ is true for *all* integers $n$ and primes $p$.

Comment: Format only applies to primes, $5\times 6$ isn't prime.  And to apply it you need $n$ prime to $p$

Comment: It might help that n^4 - 1 is evenly divisible by n-1.