# Need explain how to find sum of series

Tags: power-series

Can someone explain me how to find sum of next series:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^4 \tan^{n-1}(x)$

Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: Well Maple gives me the answer, I'd also be interested in knowing how that word.

Comment: @Matt What is the answer ?

Comment: $$\frac{-\tan^3(x)-11\tan^2(x)-11\tan(x)-1}{(\tan(x)-1)^5}$$
Obviously this only works if $|\tan(x)|<1$.

Comment: Hint : Consider the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^4t^{n-1}$$

Comment: Another hint : Consider the derivation of $n^4t^{n-1}$ with respect to $t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $n^4$ as a sum of [combinatorial polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62813) of degree $4$ or less:
$$
n^4=24\binom{n}{4}+36\binom{n}{3}+14\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}\tag{1}
$$
Next, for $|x|\lt1$, we can use the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem) and [negative binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647) to show
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{n}{k}x^{n-1}
&=\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{n}{n-k}x^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{-k-1}{n-k}(-1)^{n-k}x^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-k-1}{n}(-1)^{n}x^{n+k-1}\\
&=\frac{x^{k-1}}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^4x^{n-1}
&=\frac{24x^3}{(1-x)^5}+\frac{36x^2}{(1-x)^4}+\frac{14x}{(1-x)^3}+\frac1{(1-x)^2}\\
&=\frac{1+11x+11x^2+x^3}{(1-x)^5}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Now, just substitute $x\mapsto\tan(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n~=~?~$ Now, differentiate both sides with respect to *t*, and notice what happens... :-)