# Expressing polynomials as a linear combination of $\binom{x}{k}$

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, integers

If we have an arbitrary polynomial, $P:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, how can we express $P(x)$ as a linear combination of $\binom{x}{k}$. Is there any easy formula for finding this expression.

I am pretty sure a unique expression is guaranteed to exist because we can start with the highest degree term, let's say $a_nx^n$, and just subtract $n!a_n\binom{x}{n}$ to get an $n-1$ degree polynomial and then keep on repeating this process.

I think the most essential step is finding an expression for $x^n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\binom{x}{k}$. I have found by brute force that
$$x^0=\binom{x}{0}$$
$$x^1=\binom{x}{1}$$
$$x^2=2\binom{x}{2}+\binom{x}{1}$$
$$x^3=6\binom{x}{3}+6\binom{x}{2}+\binom{x}{1}$$
I am not sure what the pattern is. It kind of looks like pascal's triangle rows (e.g. $1,2,1$ and $1,6,6,1$ is similar to $1,3,3,1$). However, finding expressions for higher power terms is pretty exhaustive, so I was wondering if there is an easier solution?

Comment: What if you think of it in terms of inverting certain matrices? :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials gives formulas for converting between factorial polynomials and ordinary polynomials

Comment: @Wolfgang I'm not sure. I'm not very adept with advanced linear algebra, so if you could give me more hints, I might be able to formulate a solution.

Comment: @saulspatz Looking at the wikipedia page you provided, I found $x^n=\sum_{k=0}^n S(n,k)\binom{x}{k}k!$. However, I was not able to find a proof of this. Do you know how to prove the statement?

Comment: If $P(x)=c_0+c_1x+\dots+c_nx^n$ then you can write $P(x)=a_0+a_1\binom{x}{1}+\dots+a_n\binom{x}{n}$ where $a_i = i!\sum_{k=i}^{n}{k\brace i}c_k$ where ${k\brace i}$ are stirling numbers of second kind - I mentioned it in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142427). (it follows from the identity you have found, just mentioning it to link with the existing post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that (identity was noted in the comments)

$$x^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {x\choose k} {n\brace k} k!$$

This may be seen for $x$ a positive integer and since both sides are
polynomials in $x$ (recall that ${x\choose k} = x^{\underline{k}}/k!$)
it then  holds for all i.e. complex $x.$

For a combinatorial proof, consider a vector of $n$ elements where each
element may take on $x$ different values. Clearly we have $x^n$ such
vectors. On the other hand we may determine a particular vector by
choosing first the $k$ different values that appear, for a factor of
${x\choose k}$ and combine this with a partition of the $n$ slots of  the
vector into $k$ non-empty sets, for a factor of ${n\brace k}$. The sets
in the partition may be  matched to the values in $k!$ ways, thus
completing the alternate  count. We have the special case of $n=0$ which
yields one as required.

For an algebraic proof write the RHS as follows:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {x\choose k} \; k! \;
n! [z^n] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}
\\ = n! [z^n] \sum_{k=0}^n
{x\choose k} (\exp(z)-1)^k$$

Now if $n\gt x$ we may lower the upper limit of the sum to $x$ as
${x\choose k}$ is zero when $n\ge k\gt x.$ On the other hand if $n\lt
x$ we may raise the upper limit to $x$ since $(\exp(z)-1)^k = z^k +
\cdots$ and there is no contribution to $[z^n]$ when $x\ge k\gt n.$
We get

$$n! [z^n] \sum_{k=0}^x
{x\choose k} (\exp(z)-1)^k
= n! [z^n] \exp(xz) = x^n$$

as claimed.

Comment: Both of these are proofs are amazing. Great job, and thank you!